# Uniformity of the distribution of the prime numbers on the prime residue classes (mod $m$)

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Given positive integers $m$, $r$ and $n$, let $\pi(m,r,n)$ denote the number
of prime numbers $p \leq n$ in the residue class $r$ (mod $m$).
Further let $1 = r_1 < r_2 < \dots < r_{\varphi(m)} = m-1$ be the prime residues
(mod $m$), and let $\sigma \in {\rm Sym}(\{r_1, \dots, r_{\varphi(m)}\})$
be a permutation of them. Are there always infinitely many
$n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$\pi(m,\sigma(r_1),n) < \pi(m,\sigma(r_2),n) < \dots < \pi(m,\sigma(r_{\varphi(m)}),n)$?

If the answer is *yes*, are explicit bounds $B(m)$ known such that
for every permutation $\sigma$ of the prime residues (mod $m$) there is
*at least one* such $n$ less than $B(m)$?

If the answer is *no*, for which permutations $\sigma$ are there infinitely many
such $n$, and for which are not?

Comment: There is a nice survey paper related to your question here by Granville and Martin: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math.NT/0408319.pdf See especially the discussion of work by Rubinstein and Sarnak (1994) beginning on p. 24 and, if I am understanding your question correctly, the remarks (under suitable assumptions) at the top of p. 26, as well as the discussion thereafter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is conjectured to be "yes." Further, assuming GRH and GSH [Rubinstein and Sarnak, Chebyshev's Bias, Exp. Math 1994](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1048515870) even could show results on the logarithmic densities of the resepactive sets (which in particular is non-zero). I do not know about general explicit upper bounds.

Without GRH a lot less is known. The problem you mention sometimes goes by Shanks--Rényi race problem. A very good exposition of this circle of ideas is [Prime Number Races by Granville and Martin](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408319); see page 22 and subsequent ones for the discussion of Rubinstein and Sarnak's results. (Added note: this is in fact the same paper Benjamin Dickman mentions in a comment I had not seen before.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! -- So the question is open, with a conjectured answer "yes". A guess on what might be explicit upper bounds in case the conjecture holds would be nice anyway.